# Bashrc alias for C++ object file and program file combined compilation

Tags: c++, linux, bash

I am attempting to write a .bashrc alias that will compile my created object file (from a class file) along with my main program file together in C++. I have managed to make an alias for just header files, class files and program files respectively, but not with the combination of object and program files.

Here is my attempt at the function:

```
function compile() {

    local obj="${1}.o"
    local src="{2}.cpp"
    local name="{2}"
    g++ "$obj" "$src" -o "$name"

}
```

I would type this and enter it at the command line:

`compile a_class main_file`

These two files come from:

`a_class.o` , which was originally `a_class.cpp`

`main_file` is a standard `.cpp` executable file.

Using the standard g++ compilation command line prompts (e.g. `g++ a_class.cpp -c` and `g++ a_class.o main_file.cpp -o main_file`), the programs run fine. I keep getting errors for the files not existing when I use my `compile` function and the compilation fails. The errors may be from the notation of {1} and {2} but I am unfamiliar with .bashrc scripting.

Comment: The title of your post is misleading, since you are not creating an _alias_ here, which would not be suitable for your task anyway. Note that your function would behave strangely if someone invoked it as `compile '' foo`. You might want to catch this error by, i.e., replacing `${1}` by `${1:?output parameter missing}`, which would abort the execution with a meaningful error message.

Comment: Aside from this, wouldn't it make sense to name the `.o` file always analoguous to the `.cpp` file? And, you have an error in the assignment to `name`. It should be `name="$2"` or `name=$3`, if you want to pass the name of the executable as parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the "$" for src and name variables. i.e.

```
function compile() {

    local obj="${1}.o"
    local src="${2}.cpp"
    local name="${2}"
    g++ "$obj" "$src" -o "$name"

}
```

Not sure if you already know but there are decent build tools already out there like Make or CMake (build generator).

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! I'm a bonehead